# Is it ok to throw exceptions in Laravel AppServiceProvider.php?

Tags: php, laravel

I've created a Facade named "CartService" and I've bound it in AppServiceProvider.php
CartService should work only if a user is authenticated; if not, an exception must be thrown.

I have 3 questions:

1. Is it ok to throw exceptions in AppServiceProvider.php?
2. If it is ok, how should my colleague know the Facade throws an exception? Because there is no docBlock.
3. is there a better way to handle this task?

My AppServiceProvider.php is like below:

```php
public function register()
    {
        $this->app->bind(CartService::class, function () {
            if ($userId = Auth::id()) {
                return new CartService($userId);
            }

            throw new LoginRequiredException("CartService works only if the user is authenticated.");
        });
    }
```

Comment: There is better way which is `middleware` and if you want to check for only authentication, then there is already `auth` and `auth:api` middlewares in laravel

Comment: It is better to throw the exception in the `CartService` when the `$userId` is null. (of course we are assuming the `CartService` would work for an arbitrary userId not just the signed in user). If your `CartService` requires a valid user to work then it should fail to instantiate under all circumstances you attempt to instantiate it not just when it's injected via the app container